# C++ different output from the same program on two systems

Tags: c++, linux

So I'm currently working on a assignment and on my laptop it works fine but on my PC the output is gibberish.

> Enter a command:
>   a
>   Enter a command:
>   a´Zéÿ command received.

Ignoring my messed up output why is there a´Zéÿ in the output?
On my laptop the code works as intended.

Here is a small sample code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int pipefd[2];
    pid_t cpid, ppid;
    char buf[100];

    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cpid = fork();

    if (cpid == 0) {
        read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1);
        cout << buf << " command received." << endl;
    }   
    else {
        cout << "Enter a command: " << endl;
        cin >> buf;
        cout << "buf: " << buf << endl;
        size_t len = strlen(buf);
        write(pipefd[1], &buf, len);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is slighty differnt though its just
a ` command received. instead of
a command received.

E: I'm using antergos on my pc and elementary on my laptop, on both systems the terminal is urxvt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1);
```

reads one byte. Since it's one byte it's unlikely that the program has read the null terminator required by

```
cout << buf << " command received." << endl;
```

So printing is undefined behaviour; `operator<<` doesn't know where to stop reading. It might stop right away, it might run off the end of valid memory and crash the program. There is no way to be sure, and the results could be different every time.

Since there is no protocol information in the question, my only suggestion is to establish a communication protocol that informs the reader of how many bytes must be read. I like to send a known-size counter to inform the reader of size of the message before sending the message. For example,

```
uint32_t len = strlen(buf);
write(pipefd[1], &len, sizeof(len));
write(pipefd[1], &buf, len);
```

and then to read

```
uint32_t len;
read(pipefd[0], &len, sizeof(len));
read(pipefd[0], &buf, len);
```

Don't forget to check that the read succeeded and got the number of bytes you require. You may have to loop the read until you do receive the whole message.

Comment: A good protocol is not to rely on message length as the receiver may receive less than the number of digits you sent to begin with. A better method is to use delimiter. json is a good example using `{ message }`.

Comment: @alvits Totally depends on the needs of the protocol. The delimiter approach requires a reading pattern of getta-byte getta-byte getta byte, byte, byte to find the delimiter and that may not be suitable. You can carelessly overrun the input buffer for one thing. The prepended length allows the receiver to check ahead of time and make sure they have sufficient storage to handle the message and make , hopefully, one big read.

Comment: I disagree. That's why there's the third parameter to `read()`. This is the safeguard for buffer overrun. The sender is allowed to send longer than the buffer can hold. The recipient is responsible for reading it all via a loop if the buffer is shorter.

Comment: This seems to work in my sample program, i'll try it later with my assignment. I'm still super confued why i never had this issue on my laptop since i only worked on it there, i just tried it on pc today and got the errors

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the buffer or else it will contain whatever was previously in memory at that location, which is what is being printed.

Comment: But why is it working fine on my laptop that confuses me

Comment: It all comes down to chance: on your laptop, there must not be printable characters in memory at that location.

Comment: @user273032 undefined behaviour is undefined. It might even look like it works.

Comment: But it works? From the beginning when i worked on it, and if i initialize the buf its still gibberish

Comment: @user273032 It doesn't work. It looks like it works. [And then suddenly it doesn't.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73wMnU7xbwE)

Answer (score 1):

`read()` does not automatically append a null byte. It is your responsibility to append a null byte at the end of the received message.

The easiest is to get the value returned by `read()`. This value is the number of bytes read or -1 if an error is encountered. Use this return value to set the end of the string to null.

Change this line:

```
read(pipefd[0], buf, 1);
```

To:

```
int length=read(pipefd[0], buf, 99);
if (length > 0)    // length bytes was read
   buf[length]='\0';
else    // nothing was read or an error occured
   buf[0]='\0';
```

Alternatively, you can just zero out the entire buffer so you won't need to append a null byte.

Change this:

```
read(pipefd[0], buf, 1);
```

To this:

```
memset(buf,0,100);
read(pipefd[0], buf, 99);
```